# ssh-keygen in vanilla Node

Tags: node.js, ssh-keys

Is it possible to do something like `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` in pure vanilla Node?

I have a feeling [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible using the crypto module. See [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15116) github issue opened asking to support this.
There are alternatives like the one suggested by @Jiby and also lightweight wrappers around openssl which you could use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/juliangruber/keypair, which is a vanilla JS implementation